# How to pass Javascript date object (formatted datetime) from Laravel API

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, laravel

My Laravel 5 API pulls regular datetime columns from my MySQL db. My JSON datetime output looks like this:

```
2015-08-13 13:45:00
```

but the widget reading my JSON expects a JavaScript Date Object? What would be the syntax to pass my datetime as a JavaScript Date Object?

My current Laravel method looks like so:

```
public function transform($events)
{
    return [
        'startdt' => $events['event_start'],
        'enddt'   => $events['event_end'],
    ];
}
```

Here's the (partial) JSON produced:

```
{
    "events": 
[
{
    "startdt": "2015-07-15T20:49:00+00:00",
    "enddt": "2015-07-15T20:49:00+00:00"
},
{
    "startdt": "2015-07-15T20:53:00+00:00",
    "enddt": "2015-07-15T20:53:00+00:00"
},
```

This is the code I have in my widget JS file:

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('demo', ['mwl.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngTouch', 'ngAnimate'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($modal, moment, $http) {

var vm = this;
vm.calendarView = 'month';
vm.calendarDay = new Date();

$http.get('http://1.1.1.1/project/public/api/events').success(function(events) {    
    vm.events = events.events;
});
```

What would be the syntax to parse the datetime into Javascript Data Object?

Comment: JSON doesn't have a date format, so you'll need to parse the dates before you pass them to your widget. I'd suggest ISO-8601 as your transit format.

Comment: `var Date = new Date('2015-08-13 13:45:00')`. Date would be a date object instead of a string. Is it possible to use that?

Comment: @HPierce Well, I can't use that in my method (its php)?

Comment: You can't create a Javascript date object with php. You have to parse your result with Javascript like @HPierce did.

Comment: @mimo I see but I'm just not sure where to do that. I pass an array of multiples dates through an API endpoint, and my angular widget reads that array. I've just added my widget code above. Do I really need to go through all the dates in the widget and change them using var Date = new Date( startdt ); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will loop through your array and convert the date strings to date objects.

```
$http.get('http://1.1.1.1/project/public/api/events').success(function(events) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.events.length; i++) {
        events.events[i].startdt = new Date(events.events[i].startdt);
        events.events[i].enddt = new Date(events.events[i].enddt);
    }
    vm.events = events.events;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @mimo, this code worked perfecty. Now I understand